# Signing an iOS app in Xcode without a physical device

Tags: ios, xcode

I created an app few years ago, that needed some updates. I don't own a mac and don't have a physical iOS device, so when I created the app, I signed up for a macincloud instance and borrowed an iPhone which I don't have access to anymore.

The certificates were expired, so I needed to create new ones, but I admit that I don't fully understand what these Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles do and don't know exactly what I did.

In Xcode I get the following error message in the Signing section:
Failed to create provisioning profile. 
There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it.

[image]

It seems like I also deleted the previously connected device and unfortunately I can't undo those steps.

Can I submit the updates to the Apple App Store without connecting a new physical iPhone? What can I do?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this ?

Comment: No. I gave up and bought a used iPhone.